# Render array of inputs in react

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I have an array of emails (as a part of a bigger model). These are displayed in seperate rows witha  remove button for each (the address itself can be updated in the input box directly). Unfortunately I dont know how to do this in react when the inputs are renderd using a map function.
(I am converting a meteor blaze project to meteor react).

*Everything renders but how do I attach to change event so I can update my array of emails? onChange + value need to be set somehow.*

This is the map function

```
return this.data.emailGroup.emails.map((email) => {
            return (
                <div key={email} className="input-group">
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={self.handleEmailListChange} value={email}/>

                    <div className="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button"
                                className="btn btn-default remove-email"><span
                            className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        });
```

The initial state(which is populated with data from the db:

```
 getInitialState() {
      return {
          name : '',
          description: '',
          emails : [],
          newEmailAddress : ''
      }
    },
```

Upon request here is the render method(it requires a getContent method.The getcontent method is there because in meteor I need to wait for data so in the meantime I need a loading state.

```
   getContent() {
        return (

            <div className="box box-success">
                <div className="box-header with-border">
                    <h3 className="box-title">List of emails</h3>
                </div>
                <form role="form" className="form-horizontal">
                    <div className="box-body">
                        <p>Below is a list of email addresses which are added to this email group. If
                            you
                            want
                            to add more
                            you can add them one by one by inputting in the box below or add a list into
                            the
                            same box (email
                            addresses have to be seperated by either a space or ;) then press Add to add
                            to
                            the
                            list. You can edit
                            the addresses directly as well as remove them.</p>
                        <div className="input-group">
                            <input type="text" className="form-control"

                                   value={this.state.newEmailAddress}
                                   onChange={this.handleAddNewEmail}
                                   placeholder="Email addresses seperated by a space or a semicolon ; i.e. test1@test.se;test2@test.se"/>
                    <span className="input-group-btn">
                      <button type="button" onClick={this.handleAddNewEmailButton} className="btn btn-info btn-flat add-email">Add</button>
                    </span>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        {this.renderEmail()}
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    },
    render()
    {
    var contentStyle = {
        minHeight : '946px'
    };
        return (
            <div className="content-wrapper" style={contentStyle}>
                <section className="content-header">
                    <h1>
                        {this.data.emailGroup? this.data.emailGroup.name : 'hello'}
                    </h1>
                    <small> Created by: Christian Klinton</small>
                    <br/>
                    <small> Last updated by: Christian Klinton - 2015-11-12 08:10:11</small>
                    <ol className="breadcrumb">
                        <li><a href="/emailGroups"><i className="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/emailGroups">Email groups</a></li>
                        <li className="active">{this.data.emailGroup? this.data.emailGroup.name : 'loading'}</li>
                    </ol>
                </section>
                <section className="content">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <div className="box box-primary">
                                <div className="box-header with-border">
                                    <h3 className="box-title">Information</h3>

                                </div>
                                <form role="form">
                                    <div className="box-body">
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <label htmlFor="inputName">Name</label>
                                            <input type="email" className="form-control" id="name"
                                                   onChange={this.handleNameChange}
                                                   placeholder="Set the name of the email group" autoComplete="off"
                                                  value={this.state.name}/>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <label>Description</label>
                                    <textarea className="form-control" rows="3" id="description"
                                              placeholder="Enter a description what and how the template is used..."
                                              onChange={this.handleDesriptionChange}
                                              value={this.state.description}
                                    ></textarea>
                                        </div>


                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            {this.data.emailGroup? this.getContent() : <p>Loading</p> }
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <div className="col-sm-offset-8 col-sm-4">
                                <div className="pull-right">
                                    <button className="btn btn-primary">Delete all</button>
                                    <button className="btn btn-primary save">Save</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Where do you want to render it? Where is your `render` method?

Comment: @Mathletics added render method, its a bit long but you get the gist.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

React requires you to have something unique for every element in the rendered array, it's called a `key`, and it's an attribute.

If you don't know what to assign to the key, just assign it the array's indexes:

```
this.props.doors.map((door, index) => (
    <div key={index} className="door"></div>
));
```

Here's the same solution applied to your problem:

```
return this.data.emailGroup.emails.map((email, index) => {
    return (
        <div key={index} className="input-group">
            <input type="text"
                   className="form-control"
                   onChange={self.handleEmailListChange.bind(this, index)} value={email}/>
        </div>
    );
});
```

Notice how I bound `handleEmailListChange` to receive the index of the modified email. If `handleEmailListChange` accepts an index, it can update the modified email within the state:

```
handleEmailListChange: function(index, event) {
    var emails = this.state.emails.slice(); // Make a copy of the emails first.
    emails[index] = event.target.value; // Update it with the modified email.
    this.setState({emails: emails}); // Update the state.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an extensive answer. Did not get it to fully work since I use react mixin for meteor and well it uses something called "data" which I need to figure out but it should be working after that. Thanks.

Comment: @Todilo Whatever it is, you'll pull it off if you know React first ;)

Comment: Thank you for an amazing answer! For my particular problem it worked without `key` but the `.slice()` was the dealbreaker. @Zippo If I'm directly mutating the state variable but explicitly calling `setState()` again why doesnt the state get updated? Why do we need to create a copy first?

I know React has immutable state but when I call `setState()` doesn't it treat the argument as a new variable?

Answer (score 2):

You should place your `Array.map` directly inside your `render()` function. Just take care that each array element is wrapped inside a parent element (`<div>` here) and must have a unique `key={}`

```
class ArrayMap extends React.Component{
  //your functions
  handleEmailChanged(key){
    // Handle email
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {
          this.data.emailGroup.emails.map((email) => {
            <div key={email.key}>
              <button onClick={this.handleEmailChanged.bind(this,email.key)}/>
            </div>
          });
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear. Its the onChange event / value binding I need help with in the map function. Btw, due to meteor state I need to have the render of emailGroup in a seperate function(which is called in render)

Comment: I updated my answer. You pass the key as an argument to your handleChange function. And act according to that key.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for is something like this:

```
MyPage = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactMeteorData],

  getMeteorData() {
    // ...
  },

  render() {
    const emails = this.data.emailGroup.emails.map((email) => {
      return (
        <div key={email} className="input-group">
          <input type="text" className="form-control"
                 onChange={this.handleEmailListChange} value={email} />

          <div className="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button"
                    className="btn btn-default remove-email"><span
              className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" /></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return <div>
      {emails}
    </div>
  }
});
```

I changed `self` to `this`. Since you're using the ES6 arrow function, there's no need to assign `self = this`.

Comment: that seems correct but how does handleEmailListChange look like.

Comment: especilly the usage of this.data/state . I havent figured that out apparently :)

Comment: Looks like you have a few other answers with some great information in them. Are you able to piece that together to get a solution?

Comment: I figured it out. One warning for anyone reading this is that the KEY cant be email (this makes you lose focus on input when re-render occurs). Instead key should be index .(I guess email cant be used as that will change thus react dont know which one you had selected).

Comment: @Todilo No, never make `key` an index (0, 1, 2, etc). This will screw things up when React needs to remove or add items to the list. It has to be a truly unique value such as an ID, email address, full name, etc.

Comment: then to use an array of emails I have to give each one an id? Since email didn't work as that index changes when the user changes the array(which is the whole point!)

Comment: It's hard to know what's going on without a better look at your code, I'm only seeing a small part of it. But if these emails are always changing, then you're right, that won't work either. You'll have to come up with some other unique identifier that doesn't change.