# Get input from map function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i was trying to not just display a table but also update from there so i tried to set a placeholder with the actual value, now i dont know how to extract that input field when users click on update button for that row.

```
<tbody>
    {machines.map((machine) => ( <tr key={machine._id}>
    <td> <input type="text" id={`${machine._id}.tension`} placeholder={machine.tension}/> </td>
    <td><button type="button" onClick={()=> console.log(`${machine._id}.tension`)} className="btn btn-success btn-rounded btn-sm">Guardar</button></td>
    </tr>))
    }
</tbody>
```

I'm not sure if i should update the state or how because its from a map function :(

Appreciate if you can guide me on this please

Comment: Basically whatever the user typed on the input field, when the user clicks on the update you need to get the value. Correct me if am wrong on this or is this correct

Comment: check the first answer from the following thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321128/render-array-of-inputs-in-react

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you extract the row element into its own component, and when you map over the machines, your output would be a row element with the props of machine for example, that way you can handle those elements state individually for updates and such

Comment: Thank you, but still I don't know how to get thaa input field value. I though that giving it an id I could reference it but didn't work :(

Comment: At the end I got it to work extracting the Row, thank you.

Also, my question was more about the Value and onChange properties